# How to install Fedora on Xen with the LiveCD image?

Tags: fedora, xen, livecd

I've managed to get the Fedora LiveCD image (`Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-21-5.iso`) to boot in Xen using the following configuration:

```
name = 'fedora_x86_64'

memory = 1024

disk = [
    'file:/path/to/Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-21-5.iso,xvdd:cdrom,r',
    'phy:/dev/vgxen/lvfedora_x86_64,xvda,w'
]
vif = ['bridge=xenbr0']

bootloader = 'pygrub'
bootloader_args = [
    '--kernel=/isolinux/vmlinuz0',
    '--ramdisk=/isolinux/initrd0.img'
]
extra = 'root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-Live-WS-x86_64-21-5 rootfstype=auto ro rd.live.image quiet rhgb rd.luks=0 rd.md=0 rd.dm=0 nomodeset'
```

The last line was pulled from the `/isolinux/isolinux.cfg` menu entry titled "Start Fedora Live in basic graphics mode".

However, after a few moments, all I see is the following:

```
         Mounting Configuration File System...
[  OK  ] Mounted Configuration File System.
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
```

And after some more time elapses, I see:

```
         Starting Dracut Emergency Shell...
Warning: /dev/disk/by-label/Fedora-Live-WS-x86_64-21-5 does not exist
Warning: /dev/mapper/live-rw does not exist

Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"


Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
You might want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick or /boot
after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.


dracut:/#
```

It would appear that the CD isn't accessible to the VM:

```
dracut:/# ls /dev
autofs           input               snapshot  tty2   tty35  tty50  tty9
btrfs-control    kmsg                stderr    tty20  tty36  tty51  ttyS0
char             log                 stdin     tty21  tty37  tty52  ttyS1
console          loop-control        stdout    tty22  tty38  tty53  ttyS2
core             mapper              tty       tty23  tty39  tty54  ttyS3
cpu              mem                 tty0      tty24  tty4   tty55  urandom
cpu_dma_latency  net                 tty1      tty25  tty40  tty56  usbmon0
fd               network_latency     tty10     tty26  tty41  tty57  vcs
full             network_throughput  tty11     tty27  tty42  tty58  vcs1
hvc0             null                tty12     tty28  tty43  tty59  vcsa
hvc1             nvram               tty13     tty29  tty44  tty6   vcsa1
hvc2             port                tty14     tty3   tty45  tty60  vga_arbiter
hvc3             ptmx                tty15     tty30  tty46  tty61  xen
hvc4             pts                 tty16     tty31  tty47  tty62  zero
hvc5             random              tty17     tty32  tty48  tty63
hvc6             raw                 tty18     tty33  tty49  tty7
hvc7             shm                 tty19     tty34  tty5   tty8
```

`xvda` and `xvdd` aren't even visible.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @garethTheRed it's in the title - how do I perform the installation?